# this.props.function() is undefined in React app?

Tags: javascript, function, reactjs, redux

I am currently building a react-redux app and when I click the "save" button, the app should call the function addToSaved in actions/index.js. However, I am getting the error that 'this.props.addToSaved is undefined' and not a function. I define the function in actions/index.js but am wondering if I'm missing something else. Here's what I currently am doing:

in components/MainView.js:

```
'use strict';
import { addToSaved } from "../actions"

var React = require('react-native');
var {
    StyleSheet,
    Image,
    View,
    Text,
    Component,
    TouchableHighlight
} = React;


class MainView extends Component {
    onSearchPressed() {
        console.log('search pressed');
        this.props.addToSaved();
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Image style={styles.image}
                    source={{uri: pic.img_url}} />
                <TouchableHighlight style = {styles.button}
                        onPress={this.onSearchPressed.bind(this)}
                        underlayColor='#99d9f4'>
                        <Text style = {styles.buttonText}>Save</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

module.exports = MainView;
```

in actions/index.js:

```
var actions = exports = module.exports
exports.ADD_SAVED = 'ADD_SAVED'
exports.addToSaved = function addToSaved() {
    console.log('got to ADD_SAVED');
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're importing `addToSaved`, and expecting it to appear on `this.props`?

If you want it to be accessible on `this.props`, you need to pass it *into the component instance*:

```
<MainView addToSaved={addToSaved} />
```

Comment: Seems the issue, also when declaring component with props make sure you have added prop validation http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#default-prop-values

Comment: @bchemy so I should still import addToSaved but also add that line into the MainView class?

Comment: You don't need to import `addToSaved` into `MainView.js`, but you do need to import it into whatever file instantiates a `MainView` (ie. via `<MainView ...>`) and add that line.